# Eclipse IFolder from absolute path

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have the need to create an IFolder in an absolute location.
I usually have a class that does a "build" (or at least what I call a "build") for me in the workspace. The IFolder for the build-target-folder is returned by a method like this:

```
public IFolder getTargetFolder(IProject project){
    return project.getFolder("build");
}
```

Now I created a subclass of this for the "deployment" (into a directory with absolute identifier). This subclass contains the same functionality but the `getTargetfolder` routine should be like this:

```
@Override
public IFolder getTargetFolder(IProject project){
    IPath path = new Path("M:\\Path\\To\\My\\Deployment\\Directory\\");
    IFolder target = project.getFolder(path);
    return target;  
}
```

However, I run into problems and I seem to not get a handle on the folder and an exception that says the folder (`<ProjectRoot>/Path/To/My/Deployment/Directory`) does not exist. How can I specify that this should not be a relative path?

Answer (score 1):

The name given to `project.getFolder()` must be the *name of a member folder* (see the JavaDoc). 
You cannot access a file or folder with the Resources API that lies outside of the workspace. If however the `M:\\...` path lies within a projects that is part of the workspace then you can resolve the folder through `IWorkspaceRoot#getContainerForLocation()`

For example:

```
IContainer container = project.getWorkspace().getRoot().getContainerForLocation( "M:\\..." );
```

The returned `container` can be either an `IProject` or an `IFolder`. But note that the returned container does not necessarily lies within the `project`.

Some more information can be found in [Resources and the file system](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresInt_filesystem.htm)

Comment: thank you so far. do you reckon it works if it were a relative path on the same drive? i.e. can I navigate through `../../../.......` to the root and then move to the other folder?

Comment: No, a file or folder must be _known_ to the workspace, that is it must be within a project or [linked](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcepts-13.htm) from there. You may want to reconsider the general approach you are taking. Why do you want to use `IFolder` to create the _deployment build_ directory if it isn't recognized by the workspace anyway. Why don't you create a directory with hte Java file API?

Comment: The reason is to avoid double implementations. I already have local build and testing in place. I wanted to provide a convenient feature that allows to execute tests and deploy in one go. My local build uses IResources recursively and I thought it might be nice to elegantly provide a different IFolder instead of moving files after the local build and "rerouting" the links.